# Python Modules & Packages using jupyter notebook in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I'm using Jupyter Notebooks within Google CloudDatalab in Google Cloud Platform for my Python scripts. This creates *.ipynb* files.

I want to be able to create Modules and Packages using Jupyter Notebooks but it is not able to import the scripts.

For e.g.:

**mymodule.ipynb** has this:

```
def test_function():
    print("Hello World")
```

Then in **myscript.ipynb** when I try to import the above:

```
from mymodule import test_function
```

It throws an error :

> *ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>
> ----> 1 from mymodule import test_function   ImportError: No module named mymodule*

How do I create Modules & Packages using Jupyter Notebooks?

Answer (score 2):

Notebooks can't be used as modules. You need to create a python file (e.g. `mymodule.py`).

If you want you can do this from within a jupyter notebook:

```
with open('mymodule.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write('def test_function():')
    f.write('    print("Hello World")')

from mymodule import test_function
test_function()
# Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot import Jupyter Notebook in the same way as Python files (packages).

Check this link: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html

Answer (score 1):

I've received a response on a different forum which answered my question. Here is the answer:

*Put your module code into a .py file and make sure that's in the same directory as myscript.ipynb.
To create the .py file from the code currently in a notebook, you can download it from within Jupyter as a .py file and tidy it up in your text editor of choice.
Remember, the import statement is pure python syntax. It knows nothing about - and has no wish to know anything about - jupyter notebooks. It's looking for a .py file.*

This has resolved the issue.

Thanks a lot.